# Playwright tests inside docker fails to load fonts

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, github-actions, playwright, playwright-test

Currently I have Playwright tests that I am running inside Docker container both locally and in the CI. Unfortunately the tests fail on the CI with screenshot comparison error.

Upon investigation I can see that the fonts on the CI screenshots are different from the ones used to generate the expected images (also run inside docker). But this doesn't happen consistently - sometimes it happens, sometimes it doesn't. Using sharding shows that some shards pass fine and others don't inside the same job run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out - after reviewing the trace file - it turned out that the fonts are loaded from our CDN which is on a different domain from the local one inside the Docker container where the tests are running. This results in the following CORS error and the fonts are not applied.

```
Access to font at 'https://mycdn.com/fonts/my-font.woff2' from origin 'http://localhost:8003' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Furthermore this issue was strangely affecting only the tests running on `chromium` and NOT the ones on `webkit`.

After some more research I found out this [Playwright issue](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/17631) suggesting some parameters when running tests in chromium browser which actually did the job!

So the final solution was to change the chromium configuration to:

```
{
    name: 'chromium',
    use: {
        browserName: 'chromium',
        bypassCSP: true,
        launchOptions: {
            args: ['--disable-web-security'],
        },
    },
},
```